# Call two functions with context menu onclick

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

Here is a context menu item that when clicked should call two functions one after the other. The first function is ***toggleTempWhitelistStateOfHighlightedTab()*** and the second is ***suspendAllTabsInAllWindows(true)***. When I call one function only, it works but my syntax for calling two functions is not correct. Something is wrong on the ***onclick:*** line.

```
  chrome.contextMenus.create({
    title: chrome.i18n.getMessage('js_context_force_suspend_all_tabs'),
    contexts: allContexts,
    onclick: () => toggleTempWhitelistStateOfHighlightedTab(), suspendAllTabsInAllWindows(true),
  });
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you are missing some things:

```
chrome.contextMenus.create({
    title: chrome.i18n.getMessage('js_context_force_suspend_all_tabs'),
    contexts: allContexts,
    onclick: () => { toggleTempWhitelistStateOfHighlightedTab(); suspendAllTabsInAllWindows(true) }
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

You're using the JavaScript's [Arrow Function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) format here **without the {} brackets**.

However, you can only have **one expression** on the right-hand side in this case (it becomes the return value).

If you need to have **multiple statements**, you need to use brackets / semicolons:

```
() => {toggleTempWhitelistStateOfHighlightedTab(); suspendAllTabsInAllWindows(true)}
```

Note: from a logical point of view, it's probably preferable to have a named handler function. It looks cleaner, and brevity is not always the best approach.

```
function suspend_all_tabs_click() {
  toggleTempWhitelistStateOfHighlightedTab();
  suspendAllTabsInAllWindows(true)
}

chrome.contextMenus.create({
    title: chrome.i18n.getMessage('js_context_force_suspend_all_tabs'),
    contexts: allContexts,
    onclick: suspend_all_tabs_click
});
```